# Is there any way to stream video remotely and display locally simultaneously, and lessen the lag/choppiness?

Tags: usb, display, remote, streaming-video, motion

I am trying to make a infrared headset that can display my usb camera on a local monitor and stream the feed to a hyperlink simultaneously.
I want to be able to use my mobile hot spot on my phone so I can broadcast anywhere I have service.
My goal is to have a headset that can see in the dark, and have my firends be able to watch any adventure I might go on.

I was able to get the local display to work by using: luvcview -s 640x480.
I was also able to get motion to stream, however it was super choppy and laggy (I also want to address this).
But when I run luvcview while motion is streaming I get a device busy error.

Is there any way to display remotely and locally simultaneously, and lesses the lag/choppiness?